# Jenkins build log shows aborted by user

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins job ( in Network A ) runs on a slave machine ( say, server A in Network A). Jenkins job has instructions as part of the build to SSH to a server ( say server B in Network B) and execute further steps.

The job runs for about 2.5 hours. Very randomly it fails with the error message stating

```
18:24:14 Aborted by <USERNAME>
18:24:14 Finished: ABORTED
```

On server B where the build is executed, TCP keep alive is set to yes and to probe a signal every 80secs. On the kernel level, the tcpkeepalive parameter is set to 2.5hours.

I'm sure that the problem is not the timeout from this machine as i have seen a run with a duration of 157 minutes pass successfully.

The build log does neither have any further lines nor it is descriptive.

How can i effectively debug this problem? We are unable to track anything from the network traffic as there is only one session when the slave is established with SSH.

If incase, this is due to any error within the build, how can i make Jenkins throw descriptive message so that we can narrow down to the root cause?

What specifically can be tracked in network to check if this is due to network glitch?

Comment: Are you certain that it isn't being caused by a user aborting the build?

Comment: Sure, nobody is aborting the build.

Comment: Some extra questions that may or may not be helpful, just trying to get the whole picture: How is the SSH performed (is it just an `ssh` command in an Execute Shell step)? How much time has elapsed when the abort occurs? Is it consistent? Longer or shorter than usual? Is it actually `<USERNAME>` that causes the abort, or is it an actual user name? Is it the user that kicked off the job?

Comment: It is ssh within Execute shell step in the job. The abort happens at different stages. Sometimes, it could be at step 10 or step 12 ( by step i mean the execution workflow).There is a small time variation of the build. One thing that matches is that it gets aborted after 2 hours. We have two jobs that is configured to run on this node. Job 1 first completes in 2.5 hrs followed by job2. When the first job can complete in 2.5hrs, it can't be a timeout parameter specific to the node. In job 2, the job is not seen to be idle. It aborts in 2-3mins of executing a step. It throws the actual username.